# What type of IEnumerable should INotifyDataErrorInfo.GetErrors return?

Tags: silverlight-4.0

It blows my mind that the official document at MSDN doesn't say anything about what the underlying object type of the enumerable that returned by GetErrors of INotifyDataErrorInfo should be: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifydataerrorinfo.geterrors(v=vs.95).aspx

Options are: System.String, System.Object, MyCustomObject, ISomeOtherShitThatDoesntHaveAnythingToDoWithValidationWhatsoever

Can anybody explain to me how an arbitrary enumerable of object can be OK for notifying about errors without making any assumptions about its structure?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [docs for `INotifyDataErrorInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifydataerrorinfo%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) give more information:

> The validation errors returned by the GetErrors method can be of any type. However, if you implement a custom error type, be sure to override the ToString method to return an error message. Silverlight uses this string in its default error reporting.
>
> Custom error objects are useful when you provide custom error reporting in the user interface. For example, you can create a template for the reporting ToolTip that binds to an ErrorLevel property in order to display warnings in yellow and critical errors in red.

There's a link in the Examples section of `GetErrors` back to that documentation:

> For an example of an implementation of this method, see the `INotifyDataErrorInfo` class overview.

I agree it's less clear than it might be, but the documentation is there...

Comment: Thanks, it would be nice to see that part on the page directly related to GetErrors method :)

Comment: @bonomo: Agreed, but it only took me about a minute to find it, never having used this interface before :)

Comment: I spent 20 minutes for nothing instead of working on a real problem, I  am simply not smart enough and don't have much time to solve MSDN puzzles :)

Comment: +1 The documentation for the .NET 4.5 version of this interface is extremely sparse.  I didn't think about checking the original documentation on the Silverlight side.  Thanks.